# In Chrome extension, is it possible to get the original HTTP response body before it is being parsed by the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

When an HTTP response is received by the browser, the browser changes it during the parsing. Namely, the page as it presented is not completely identical to the body of the HTTP response.

My questions:

1. Is it possible for Chrome extension to get the original HTTP response body before it is being parsed by the browser?
2. Is it possible to do this in other browsers?
3. Is it possible to do this using plugins?

If there are examples, I will be glad to get them or references to them.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. In a non-[devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) extension only via [chrome.debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) and [getResponseBody](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-1/Network/#method-getResponseBody) 2. no idea 3. Fiddler + its chrome extension, probably (and maybe a few others that use the  same principle)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show more research effort - what *is* available for plug ins, and why can't you use them? Currently, this question is not specific and too broad.